# ERROR: syntax error at or near ";" at CREATE TABLE

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

I study Postgresql. I've just installed PG on Ubuntu, checkout as user "postgres" and run psql commandline. But when I try to execute commands like SHOW, CREATE and so on, I get:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near ";"

```
postgres@comp:/etc/postgresql/10/main$ psql
psql (10.5 (Ubuntu 10.5-1.pgdg18.04+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \c
You are now connected to database "postgres" as user "postgres".
postgres=# CREATE TABLE TEST1
postgres-# ;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 2: ;
        ^
postgres=# CREATE TABLE TEST1;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE TEST1;
                          ^
postgres=# CREATE TABLE 'TEST1';
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'TEST1'"
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE 'TEST1';
                     ^
postgres=#
```

I tried to find the same issues on Stackoverflow, but no result. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I can comment on what you _aren't_ doing.  You aren't actually specifying any column names or definitions, types, etc.  Try entering a valid `CREATE TABLE` definition, and see if that works.

Comment: Please see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html) for a detail description on the syntax of the `create table` statement. You might want to start with the [tutorial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-table.html) that contains many examples with the correct syntax. Add make sure you understand the [difference between identifiers and strings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html)

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs because the table structure is not specified. You should execute something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST1 (id bigserial primary key NOT NULL);
```

More information https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html